# How to convert from 'T' to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to serialize a generic object to XML:

```
public void SaveEntry(T Entry) {
    try {
        XmlSerializer inst = new XmlSerializer(Entry);
    } catch { ... }
}
```

But I'm getting an error `CS1503`:

> Error [CS1503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503) Argument 1: cannot convert from `T` to `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You don't pass the object to the serializer's constructor, you pass it to the appropriate method. Take a look at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the object you're wanting to serialize to the constructor for the serializer:

```
var inst = new XmlSerializer(Entry);
```

However, this is invalid; per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?view=net-5.0), the constructor you're attempting to utilize accepts a `Type` as an argument.

> Initializes a new instance of the XmlSerializer class that can serialize objects of the specified type into XML documents, and deserialize XML documents into objects of the specified type.
>
> ```
> public XmlSerializer (Type type);
> ```

As such, you can invoke the constructor using `typeof` to specify the type of `T`:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

This is likely what you want to do, and, doing so will resolve your CS1503 error. Furthermore, to serialize your `Entry` you'll need to call the `Serialize` method:

```
var xmlData = string.Empty;
using (var textWriter = new StringWriter()) {
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter)) {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, Entry);
        xmlData = textWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to pass the relevant `Type` object to the constructor.** The object gets passed to `Serialize`

```
XmlSerializer inst = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
var xml = inst.Serialize(yourStream, Entry);
```